# Currency formatting in React / Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

Good afternoon folks!

I'm using React NumberFormat for currency formatting, it works well, but I couldn't reproduce with it the behavior I want for my page.

I would like the user to type in the 1010 input, and the input automatically corrects it to  $ 10.10.

However, all the methods I found, when the user types 1010, he corrects it for $ 1010.00.

How do I get to this behavior in real time in the input? As soon as the user types, it is already formatting.

Appreciate!

I need a regular expression or code, where:

I type - return code

```
1010 ===> 10.10
1000 ====> 10.00
1050 =====> 10.50
100050 ====> 1,000.50
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add your best not working attempt!

Comment: So divide it and format it.... `var str = '1010'; console.log((Number(str)/100).toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }));`

Comment: I gonna try this...Thank you!

Comment: I need a regular expression or code, where:

I type ===> return code

1010 ===> 10.10
1000 ====> 10.00
1050 =====> 10.50
100050 ====> 1,000.50

Comment: For your requirement, this react package would work better - https://github.com/ianmcnally/react-currency-masked-input.

Answer (score 1):

You can try making a "format" function like below:

```
function formatCurrency(currencyString) {   
    let firstHalf = currencyString.substring(0, currencyString.length - 2);
    let secondHalf = currencyString.substring(currencyString.length - 2, currencyString.length);
    return parseFloat(`${firstHalf}.${secondHalf}`).toLocaleString('en-EN', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'});
}

// example use case: 
let cur = formatCurrency('1010'); // returns: '$10.10'
cur = formatCurrency('101010') // returns: '$1,010.10'
```

This way you are always getting the last two characters on the right side of the decimal, as you're trying to do, and using localization to properly format the number.